# Поля разделов в битриксе

Tags: битрикс

Есть задача - другой дизайн шапки ( на отдельных страницах ). Как я вижу решение 
 - создать поле в разделе в виде выпадающего списка с указанием дизайна
 - на базе значения в header.php подгружать файл внешнего вида

Но я не нашел способа добавить какое-либо поле кроме простого текстового через настройки структуры. 
Как тогда лучше поступить?

Answer (score 1):

Все гораздо проще. Создайте отдельный шаблон: `Администрирование->Настройки->Настройки продукта->Сайты->Шаблоны сайтов`. В административной панели в настройках сайта задайте условия применения шаблона: `Администрирование->Настройки->Настройки продукта->Сайты->Список сайтов`. Переходите в настройки конкретного сайта в секции `Шаблон сайта` для основного шаблона в поле `тип условия` выбираете `без условия`, а для нового ставите тип условия `для папки или файла`, а в поле `условие` указываете папку раздела к которой применять данный шаблон. Если применить надо к нескольких разделам, которые в разных корневых папках, то или добавляете шаблон столько раз сколько надо, либо выбираете тип условия `выражение PHP` и в условие подставляете регулярку. Вот [пример](http://prntscr.com/nttnch) применения отдельного шаблона для раздела с обучающими курсами.

Comment: "Все гораздо проще" ) спасибо, изучу